# Create React App env variables undefined when using Craco build in Heroku

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, craco

I'm deploying an Express app (Node.js/React) to Heroku and have set my env vars in Heroku using the config vars in Settings in the Heroku Dashboard. On the server side, I can access them using `process.env` without any problems. However, in my client, my `process.env` vars are returning `undefined`.

I have prefixed them with `REACT_APP`, and the issue seems to be related to the `craco build` script in my `client/package.json` that is called during the build stage of the Heroku deployment. If I set this to `react-scripts build`, the environment variables behave as expected, however, my TailwindCSS config then fails.

I can also have a `.env` file in the client, but I need different values depending on the stage of the Heroku pipeline, and  `NODE_ENV` is always `"production"` once deployed to Heroku so I can't think of a way to have different values depending on the stage.

Is there a way for `craco build` to get the `REACT_APP` vars from the Heroku config vars during deployment in the same way `react-scripts build` does?

Answer (score 1):

There is a npm package specifically build to use .env variables with craco: https://github.com/djdmbrwsk/dotenv-cra